# Insert Data into Table from data table based on another table's data

Tags: sql-server, datatable, insert

I have one data table as a parameter of stored procedure. And I am inserting data into table from that data table.

Table `Invoice`:

```
ID     Version
----+---------
11      1    
20      1
11      2
```

DataTable `@invoiceData`:

```
ID
--
11
21
```

Now I want to insert data from `@invoiceData` to `Invoice`. if `ID` from `@invoiceData`  exists in `Invoice` table then new record for that id will be added with `Version` increased by 1. And if `ID` doesn't exist `Version` will be 1.

Here's what I am doing right now :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Invoice] ([ID], [Version])
    SELECT 
        inv.ID,
        CASE 
           WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Invoice iv WHERE iv.ID = inv.ID) IS NOT NULL               
              THEN (SELECT MAX (ISNULL(iv.VersionId, 0)) + 1 
                    FROM dbo.Invoice iv 
                    WHERE iv.ID = inv.ID)  
           ELSE 1 
        END,
    FROM
        @invoiceData inv
```

But I am getting an error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Output I want :

Table `Invoice`:

```
ID     Version
----+---------
11      1    
20      1
11      2
11      3
21      1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
INSERT INTO Invoice (ID, Version)
SELECT 
    inv.ID,
    (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(i1.Version), 0) + 1 FROM Invoice i1 where i1.ID = i.ID)
FROM @InvoiceData i
```

Rationale: the correlated subquery, that uses an aggregate function without a `group by` clause, will always return a single row. If the given `id` already exists, then we take its maximum value and increment it. If it does not yet exist, `MAX()` returns `NULL`, which we turn to `0` with `COALESCE()`, and then increment.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f397ad8f8fa85e643c960d4dc358ff9)**

Answer (score 1):

limit the result of your subquery using `TOP`

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Invoice] (
    [ID],
    [Version]
)
SELECT 
    inv.ID,
    Case when 
            coalesce((select top 1 1 from dbo.Invoice iv where iv.ID = inv.ID), 0) != 0
        then 
            (select max(ISNULL (iv.VersionId, 0)) + 1 FROM dbo.Invoice iv WHERE iv.ID = inv.ID)  else 1 end,
    from @invoiceData inv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Invoice] (
    [ID],
    [Version]
)
SELECT 
    inv.ID,
    Case when (select TOP 1 ID from dbo.Invoice iv where iv.ID = inv.ID) is not null then (SELECT MAX (ISNULL (iv.VersionId, 0)) + 1 FROM dbo.Invoice iv WHERE iv.ID = inv.ID)  else 1 end,
    FROM @invoiceData inv
```

I think ...you re missing ...top 1 value(ID) from table...

Reason...**Select 1 return multiple value**....that why you re getting
this type of error

> But I am getting Error : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is
>   not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when
>   the subquery is used as an expression.